# Instagram: Can followers of a private user I also follow view a my private reel if I tag it with that user?

Tags: privacy, instagram, followers

I have a private Instagram account and I follow another private account that follows me back.

I follow no other accounts and I have no other followers.

The private account I follow does have other followers and follows other accounts.

I posted a reel where I tagged that private account. The reel has a view count of 4 and I'm wondering how that view count was calculated.

Is this happening because her  followers can view the reel or maybe she can forward it to others?

If I watch the reel myself the view count doesn't change so I'm wondering how there could be 4 views given my privacy settings and my lack of followers.